# Dolphin Publisher - how do I re-sort its "sentences?"

Tags: windows-7, accessibility

I'm using Dolphin Publisher (http://yourdolphin.com) to create a DAISY book.  It depends on "sentences" that you declare in their HTML editor, but there are a few sentences it "skips" or if I step through them, it lists them in the wrong order.

I can't make it synch to the WAV properly unless the sentences will appear "in order."  argh - anyone else use this and able to help?

(Dolphin Publisher 3.5.3 . On a Windows 7 Machine because that's what work insists on for this.)

(alas, no tags exist here for Dolphin or Daisy.)

Answer (score 0):

I can answer *this* specific question -- in the main (not HTML-edit) view, under Edit, there is a "sort events" dialog.

(The problem is that now Dolphin Publisher is "seeing" mega-sentences underlying the regular ones, and I can't undo those, despite adding each actual sentence as a distinct "sentence" in their HTML editor.  I am having a lot of chaos in general here.)